# Export plot in pdf format using legendMaker

Tags: export, legending, pdf-format

I am playing with the function `legendMaker` coming from the answer of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines) question. I am using same data form answer.

```
opts = Sequence[Background -> LightOrange, RoundingRadius -> 10];
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}};
points = Table[{#1, Log[b, #2]} & @@@ data, {b, 2, 10, 2}];
plot = ListLinePlot[points];
labels = Table[Row[{Subscript["Log", b], x}], {b, 2, 10, 2}]
newPlot = Overlay[{plot, legendMaker[labels, opts]}, Alignment -> {Right,    Top}]
```

Please note that the function `legendMaker` is defined in the mentioned answer and not copied in my question.

The problem is that when I try to `Export` the `newPlot` in **pdf** format using command

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "newPlot.pdf"}], newPlot, 
ImageSize -> 1200, "CompressionLevel" -> 0]
```

I get too much white space on left side of the plot. Other formats such as png are working fine, but the quality is worse.

Probably this is because of the legend that is used. Same problem is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130415/problems-with-exporting-graphics-in-pdf-format). Methods (`Rasterize` and `Inset`) mentioned in the that post are not working in my case. Could somebody please help me how to get rid off white space on the left size of the plot and at the same time to have plot in pdf format?